# Loop through table form with Javascript and create objects from the values

Tags: javascript, jquery, handlebars.js

Im trying to loop through a table form and create objects from each row. Each row contains 2-3 input fields and the values from those should be the properties of the object. The object should only be stored if the checkbox corresponding to the that row is checked.

EDIT: I came up with a solution. Im new to Javascript so please give input if this can be improved somehow.

Html:

```
 <table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">Markera</th>
      <th scope="col">Användarnamn</th>
      <th scope="col">Namn</th>
      <th scope="col">Omdöme i Canvas</th>
      <th scope="col">Examinationsdatum</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {{#each userArray}}
    <tr class="the_row">
      <th scope="row">1</th>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox"/></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="username" value="
      {{this.userName}}"  readonly /></td>
      <td>{{this.firstName}}</td>
      <td>{{this.grade}}</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="date"/></td>
    </tr>
    {{/each}}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

JS:

```
let users = [];

$("#btn").on("click", function () {
event.preventDefault();

$(".table tr").each(function () {

let user = {};

$(this).find("input").each(function () {


  if($(this).attr("name") =='checkbox' && $(this).prop("checked")
  == true){
    user[$(this).attr("name")] = $(this).prop("checked");

  }
  else{
    user[$(this).attr("name")] = $(this).val();
  }

  });

  
  if(user.checkbox===true){
    users.push(user);
  }
});

console.log(users);
});
```

Sorry about the intending is the JS file.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and this [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Code that you have worked on to solve the problem should include a [mcve], and be included in your question, _not as an image_.

Comment: Ids have to be **unique**

Comment: @Andreas Yes thank you that solved one part of my problem!

Answer (score 1):

If you are just submitting a form, you could use `FormData` to gather the field names and their values, then turn that into an object.

```js
const form = document.querySelector('.myForm')

form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault()
  const object = {};
  const myFormData = new FormData(form)
  myFormData.forEach((value, key) => object[key] = value);
  console.log(object)
})
```

```html
<form class="myForm">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>1</th>
        <td><label>checkbox: <input type="checkbox" name="row1checkbox"/></label></td>
        <td><label>text: <input type="text" name="row1text" /></label></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>2</th>
        <td><label>checkbox: <input type="checkbox" name="row2checkbox"/></label></td>
        <td><label>text: <input type="text" name="row2text" /></label></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>3</th>
        <td><label>checkbox: <input type="checkbox" name="row3checkbox"/></label></td>
        <td><label>text: <input type="text" name="row3text" /></label></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

A  (not that minimal but) [reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to create an object from the current values of input/select elements in the document (note: no form used here).

[See also](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-o6f6pt?file=index.js)

```js
getMyValues();

const handle = evt => {
  if (/input|select/i.test(evt.target.nodeName)) {
    return getMyValues();
  };
}
document.addEventListener(`click`, handle);
document.addEventListener(`keyup`, handle);

function getMyValues() {
  console.clear();
  const valuesObj = [...document.querySelectorAll('input, select')]
    .reduce( (acc, inp) => {
      if (/radio|checkbox/i.test(inp.type)) {
        acc[inp.id] = inp.checked ? `on:${inp.value}` : `off:${inp.value}`;
      }
      // note: you may want to include types like range/search/url etc. 
      // See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input
      if (/text|number|textarea|date/i.test(inp.type)) {
        acc[inp.id] = inp.value || `empty`;
      }
      
      if (inp.constructor === HTMLSelectElement) {
        acc[inp.id] = inp.value;
      }

      return acc;
    }, {});
        
  document.querySelector(`pre`).textContent = `Your values:\n${
    JSON.stringify(valuesObj, null, 2)}`;
  }
```

```css
body {
  font: 12px/15px normal verdana, arial;
  margin: 2rem;
}

pre {
  position: absolute;
  width: 45vw;
  left: 50vw;
  top: 1rem;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #AAA;
}

input,
select {
  margin-bottom: 6px;
}
```

```html
<pre></pre>
<p>
  <input type="number" value="4" id="someNumber"> some number<br>
  <input type="checkbox" value="cb4" id="someCheckbox"> some checkbox<br>
  <input type="text" placeholder="some text" id="someText" value="tx txt text"> some text<br>
  <input type="text" placeholder="some text" id="someText2"> some text<br>
  <select id="selectSome">
    <option value="v1">v1</option>
    <option value="v2" selected>v2</option>
    <option value="v3">v3</option>
  </select><br>
  <select id="selectSome2">
    <option value="nothing selected yet">select one</option>
    <option value="vv1">vv1</option>
    <option value="vv2">vv2</option>
    <option value="vv3">vv3</option>
  </select><br>
  <input type="radio" name="someRadio" id="radio1" value="r1">r1<br>
  <input type="radio" name="someRadio" id="radio2" value="r2">r2<br>
  <input type="radio" name="someRadio" id="radio3" value="r3">r3
</p>
```